# How to completely remove LAMP in Ubuntu 16.04 to be ready for a fresh installation

Tags: apache2, mysql, lamp, phpmyadmin

I installed LAMP:

```
apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-mysql mysql-server
```

and `phpmyadmin`.

Unfortunately, I did not put a password in when I was questioned to do so. Now I cannot log into mysql. I think there is a policy now that forbidds root access without password.

That is why i wanted to completely remove all packages and configuration and do a fresh install of LAMP where I will get asked to set the password again.

I used `purge` and `whereis` and `dpkg -l mysql* | grep ii | awk '{print $2}'` to make sure I deinstalled all files (i also did this for apache2) but on re-installing the dialog for the password does not come up.

How do I find and delete all files for the LAMP and phpmyadmin to be able to install everything newly from scratch?

Comment: I now managed to log in via terminal using this post (http://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04) but anyway the question is still relevant because phpmyadmin requires (root)-users to have a password which i cannot set.

Comment: You can log in to the mysql server (>5.7) via root linux user only, without password. Have a look [at related question](http://askubuntu.com/a/763359/325029) for what you can do in your case.

Comment: Yes, I did this. Anyway, my question still remains relevant, I think. Because one should be able to remove all files concerning a package to be able to install it completely new.

Comment: LAMP is actually a number of individual packages, so each package needs to be removed individually. See this post: How do I remove the LAMP stack so I can start over?   http://askubuntu.com/questions/50101/how-do-i-remove-the-lamp-stack-so-i-can-start-over

Comment: Maybe [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/887375/655910) will solve your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the LAMP stack so I can start over?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50101/how-do-i-remove-the-lamp-stack-so-i-can-start-over)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but the other question is five years old. There are probably a lot of differences now in regards to relevant packages and directories.

Comment: @Siraj that question is so old the answer mentions php5.