# PhpMyAdmin, Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using ubuntu 2018, I have just installed phpMyAdmin but I get this message:

> #1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

I have followed this steps:
[Cannot enter phpmyadmin as root (MySQL 5.7)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763336/cannot-enter-phpmyadmin-as-root-mysql-5-7?answertab=active#tab-top)

but I get other error in the terminal:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysql';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost'
```

**EDIT**
I have found a solution in the documentation:

```
sudo mysql
```

Then

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'nom_utilisateur_choisi'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mot_de_passe_solide' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
QUIT;
```

But when I have copied and paste the last command , it has directly created user with name "**nom_utilisateur_choisi**" and password "**mot_de_passe_solide**".

How can I edit or delete them to repeat again ?

Comment: you need the required password on `.......  IDENTIFIED BY '<your-password>';`

Comment: Can you show my Edit please ?

Comment: for remove and recreate user see https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04/784347#784347 sir