# MariaDB: Default password authentication not good enough?

Tags: mysql, password, authentication, plugins, mariadb

I've been researching for a couple of hours the "best practice" to create a second account for the mysql database using password authentication instead of the `auth_socket` / `unix_socket`.

By this guide [safest and permanent solution to create a new user mariadb](https://askubuntu.com/a/763359/924437), the authentication uses no plugin. In other guides, people add the `mysql_native_password` as the plugins (e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029535/924437)).

However, by the mariadb [documentations about mysql_native_password](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-mysql_native_password/), they recommend to use [ed25519 plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-ed25519/) instead. I have not seen a single guide online to use this one with mariadb.

Now, which authentication method/plugin should is use and whats the big differenece between the `no plugin` and `ed25519`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your [ed25519 plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-ed25519/) link:

> MySQL has used SHA-1 based authentication since version 4.1. Since
> MariaDB 5.2 this authentication plugin has been called
> mysql_native_password. Over the years as computers became faster, new
> attacks on SHA-1 were being developed. Nowadays SHA-1 is no longer
> considered as secure as it was in 2001. That's why the ed25519
> authentication plugin was created.
>
> The ed25519 authentication plugin uses Elliptic Curve Digital
> Signature Algorithm to securely store users' passwords and to
> authenticate users. The ed25519 algorithm is the same one that is used
> by OpenSSH. It is based on the elliptic curve and code created by
> Daniel J. Bernstein.

If security is a concern to you and it should, I would follow MariaDB best pratice and use the ed25519 plugin.

By default, without any plugin, [Mariadb](https://blog.pythian.com/hashing-algorithm-in-mysql-password-2/) uses a `sha1(sha1("password"))`, well actually `SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1("this_is_a_random_string")))`, and `sha1` is unsafe. As usual, follow best practice, use the ed25519 plugin - if there is a best practice concerning security, follow it, there usually is a good reason - nobody is gonna write up a best practice for something if there is not a good reason.

Comment: I've also read that part, but this is the `mysql_native_password` plugin. My big question is about the `non-plugin-method`.

Comment: I have amended my answer.

Comment: This explains a lot, however, eventough that ed25519 should be used, it's not supported by phpmyadmin.

Comment: In that case you should use the potentially unsafe password scheme for the phpadmin user. `alter user 'username'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'password';` not ideal, but if you have to use phpadmin, no other choice, for the moment ...