# How to log in as root to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a password secured mariadb server on an Ubuntu 18.04 server.  I can log in at the command line using

`mysql -u root -p` with my password.

But when I go to https://myserver.com/phpmyadmin/index.php` I can not log in as root.  This is the error I see:

```
#1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

```
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I am definitely using the same password I use on the command line.

I can log in as user `phpmyadmin` with the password I entered during `dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot enter phpmyadmin as root (MySQL 5.7)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763336/cannot-enter-phpmyadmin-as-root-mysql-5-7)

Comment: *deleted - checking*

Answer (score 2):

@Søren gave an important link that is very close but not exactly the same:

[Cannot enter phpmyadmin as root (MySQL 5.7)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763336/cannot-enter-phpmyadmin-as-root-mysql-5-7)

The answer is:  root user can not log in at `phpmyadmin` interface, so root privileges must be given to another user (ex `phpmyadmin` user).

The actual answer that worked was not marked as correct on that page.  It was given by @Hemamalini and it is:

```
CREATE USER 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 PHP 7.2 PHPMyAdmin 4.6.6