# Ubuntu 18.04 phpmyadmin refresh error

Tags: mysql, php, password, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin on ubuntu 18.04, I enter my username and password correctly, but the page is refreshed and there is no error. token id is generated. (http://my-ip/phpmyadmin/index.php?lang=tr&collation_connection=utf8mb4_unicode_ci&token=83d9c6ae770adc7420fgfdsg63e2cbf) When I enter my username and password wrong, the page gives an error. However, when I enter my username and password correctly, when I press the go button, only the page is refreshed. I can't go inside. How can i solve this problem?

Thank you so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot enter phpmyadmin as root (MySQL 5.7)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763336/cannot-enter-phpmyadmin-as-root-mysql-5-7)

Comment: No. I get the same error not only as root but other users I created. the page is constantly being refreshed. I can't go inside. but token id is generated